# Add xinput to the start up sequence of LXDE

Tags: startup, lxde

I want these 2 commands to run on boot.

```bash
xinput --set-prop "Razer Razer DeathAdder" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 4
xinput --set-prop "Razer Razer DeathAdder" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1
```

I tried putting these 2 commands `/etc/rc.local`, `.zshrc`, also in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`, but nothing seems to happen. Any help please?

Comment: Try putting them in your `.xinitrc`.

Comment: I dont have a .xinitrc

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou why would `.xinitrc` be read unless `xinit` is used to start X?

Comment: @trttrt : yes, but you would create it.  Anyway, terdon is probably right, try to follow his answer.

Comment: @terdon : well, I do use it (through `startx` in my `.bash_profile`) so other people might as well…  Besides, it has never been clear to me where to put such commands as well as it's different on almost every setup, hence the suggestion.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou I used to use it as well but I would be very surprised if that were how lubuntu is setup.

Answer (score 4):

As Skippy said, you should add them to the `~/.xinitrc` file. This is because:

- `/etc/rc.local` executes at boot time, before the Xserver is up
- `.zshrc` gets loaded only when you start a zsh shell.
- `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` needs an special name and format: they should be named `<something>.conf` and has proper `exec=` values and be stored in `/etc/xdg/autostart/`.

**The above will not work**

You only need to source the scripts lines in the `~/.xinitrc` or in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` for system wide proposes.

This should work:

```bash
sudo sh -c "echo 'xinput --set-prop \"Razer Razer DeathAdder\" \"Device Accel Constant Deceleration\" 4' >> /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc"
sudo sh -c "echo 'xinput --set-prop \"Razer Razer DeathAdder\" \"Device Accel Velocity Scaling\" 1' >> /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc"
```

Of course, the said commands should work if you use the terminal, otherwise your are doing nothing. Then reboot your system and ta-da.

Comment: Sorry, but I put the commands (tried all the combinations) but still they will not run on boot. Do I need to make it executable? I did it, nothing

Comment: This is what I get: xinit is already the newest version.

Comment: I created ~/.xinitrc, put the commands in, didn't work. Then I deleted ~/.xinitrc (since it didn't work), and put my commands in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc, and nothing happened.

Comment: The commands work fine in the terminal.

Comment: With the new answer I am getting this: "Razer: 1: Razer: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string"

Comment: Now, I had to escape the quote marks.

Comment: Could you help me please?

Comment: I am sorry, but it doesnt work. I don't know why this is happening

Comment: Does Lubuntu use `xinit`? It doesn't have a login manager? `~/.xinitrc` is only read if X is started via `xinit` and not a login manager.

Comment: @terdon I started to think that Ubuntu isn't playing fair here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really see how `.xinitrc` is relevant here. That file is read by `xinit`, an old way of starting an X session and one you are almost certainly not using. In most modern Linux systems, the X session is started by a login manager service, for example `lightdm` or `gdm2` or whatever and not by `xinit`.

Anyway, according to the [LXDE wiki](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession#autostart), you need to add these lines to `$HOME/.config/lxsession/<profile>/autostart`. Change `<profile>` to whatever you have in `$HOME/config/lxsession`. Just edit (or create of it does not exist) the file and add the relevant lines to it:

```
xinput --set-prop "Razer Razer DeathAdder" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 4                                 
xinput --set-prop "Razer Razer DeathAdder" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting `xinput` command into a shell script and adding that script to be executed via `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` worked for me.

Example:

```shellsession
$ cat ~/bin/set-touch
#!/bin/bash

xinput set-prop "ADS7846 Touchscreen" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1.09588 0 -0.0565 0 -1.11 1.057 0 0 1
    
$ cat ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart 
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@bin/set-touch
@midori -e Fullscreen -a https://start.duckduckgo.com/
```