# Start up commads in Lubuntu 2

Tags: ubuntu, zsh, oh-my-zsh, lubuntu

After posting my question here, [Add xinput to the start up secuence of LXDE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97735/start-up-commads-in-lubuntu)

I got no answer so here it is. I have these 2 commands:

```
xinput --set-prop "Razer Razer DeathAdder" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 4                                 
xinput --set-prop "Razer Razer DeathAdder" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1
```

Which I want to run on start up. I am using zsh shell.

I tried putting these 2 commands `/etc/rc.local`, `.zshrc`, `.zlogin`, also in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` , also in `/.xinitrc` and `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` but nothing seems to happen. Could somebody let me know what is going on please, and why none of these is working?

Here is my current `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` file (ignore the numbers (vim)):

```
  1 #!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  3 # /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  4 #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  5 # global xinitrc file, used by all X sessions started by xinit (startx)                                                                                                                                                                  
  6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  7 # invoke global X session script                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  8 . /etc/X11/Xsession                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  9                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  10 /usr/bin/xinput --set-prop "Razer Razer DeathAdder" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 4          
  11 /usr/bin/xinput --set-prop "Razer Razer DeathAdder" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1
```

Could somebody explain to me what is goign on ? Why nothing is happening?
I tried everything, rebooted, and the $%^&* commands will just not run.

Any help please?

Comment: You _did_ get an answer on the other question, please don't repost the same question twice.

Comment: @terdon, find the answer, and let me know

Answer (score 0):

> I tried putting these 2 commands /etc/rc.local, .zshrc, .zlogin,

Probably not a great idea since X may not be running at that point, and/or you may not actually get a login shell because of the GUI.  I'd think `.zshrc` might work but I don't know anything about `zsh`.

> also in /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart

Seems like a good place...but apparently it didn't work...the issue might be you have an autostart in $HOME that overrides that one.

> also in /.xinitrc and /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc but nothing seems to happen.

Was the first one supposed to be `~/.xinitrc`?  If so, keep in mind that one will be used and not the one in `/etc` -- never both (unless they are explicitly sourced in, which would be unusual).

I'm going to take a guess that you do have an `~/.xinitrc` created by the system, but you did what you appear to have done with your current `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` -- you put the commands *at the end*.

The problem with that is the old last line was probably something like:

```
lxde
```

Or `lxde-session` or whatever.  That's the command that starts your DE, but guess what?  It doesn't execute in the background, and it doesn't complete until you leave X.  You want to run your xinput commands *before* anything else in the xinitrc file.

A good way to figure out which file is used is to put something like:

```
echo "This is ~/.xinitrc" >> $HOME/xinit.log"
```

at the very top of all of them (notice they are actually shell scripts), then check that log after you start X.  Make sure to use `>>` and not `>`.